# Can you Twisp off-turn?

Tags: penny-arcade-gamers-vs-evil

My opponent attacks, and I have a Baby Ninja and a Twisp in hand.
I play the Baby Ninja, and she attacks again. Can I play Twisp to duplicate the Baby Ninja? It seems like you should be able to, but there is an explicit list in the rule book, that doesn't  cover PVP Defense.

Edit for clarity: This question relates to Penny Arcade: Gamers Vs Evil and NOT to the Penny Arcade Card Game.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. You don't **play** PVP Defense cards, you **use** abilities on those cards. **Twisp** doesn't mention copying PvP Defense abilities. This is supported by the fact that **play** is only used in reference to a player's own turn. From the correct [Rulebook](http://files.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/7zxj4c7sa5/PA_Rulebook_FINAL.pdf?).

> **PVP ATTACKS AND DEFENSES** - Some cards allow you to make a PvP Attack against the other players in the game. When you play a card with a PvP Attack ability, each other player has an opportunity to block the attack with a card that has a PvP Defense ability. A player **using a PvP Defense card’s ability** negates the attack only for that defending player.
>
> **Twisp**: Catsby’s special card Twisp simply **copies all abilities of any other card played in a turn**, including Tokens, Power, card drawing, and PvP Attacks. If the card would be deleted, then Twisp is deleted.
>
> **Baby Ninja** - {2}, **+1 Power**, **PVP Defense:** Discard this card to block a **PVP Attack**. If you do, draw a card.
>
> Jim Darkmagic: Jim’s special hero power must be used before you **take any actions or play any cards for your turn**.